# Finding base address U-boot Android image from /dev/block/mmcblk0boot0

Tags: ida, disassembly, hardware

Currently I am stuck finding the base address for IDA to disassemble the boot image correctly.

The `img` file is coming from `/dev/block/mmcblk0boot0` (`mcc_utils` is executing: `cat bootarea.img > dev/block/mmcblk0boot0` to restore this image). And looking at the string output it shows that it prolly is U-boot `U-Boot 2011.12 (Nov 04 2016 - 12:13:11)` and the platform is running android 4.4.

[image: Start of image]

The image starts with `0x19034` and then zero's until `0x200` which seem to contain some sort of checksum.Then at `0x600` certain address appear all starting with `0xE004xxxx`.

At `0x660` the first opcodes seem to placed and just before that `0xBACODE` is shown 3 times.

I have tried to drop the image file until `0x600` and several different base addresses. But I don't seem to be able to get all offset correctly in IDA. There are a lot of strings at the bottom which could be matched.

The image file can be downloaded [here](https://ufile.io/18rbo).

Hopefully someone can help me finding the correct offset and base address.

Answer (score 1):

I removed the correct amount of bytes and now set the base address to 0xE0040000 and it works :)